# Explanation needed for the following steps (is my step right)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

I have summation as given below $$\sum_{i}x_iy_i$$ where $y_i$ are independent random variables and $x_i$ may depend on each other but they are independent of $y_i's$. I am interested in finding the expectation $$E[\sum_{i}x_iy_i\quad |\quad x_iy_i\leq c, \forall i]$$where $c$ is some positive constant. Now I write $$E[\sum_{i}x_iy_i\quad |\quad x_iy_i\leq c, \forall i]=E_{x_i}\left[\sum_i x_i E_{y_i}\left[y_i1(y_i\leq cx_i^{-1})\right]\right]$$ I want to ask is it right thing to do? Or there should be a division by some probability (e.g. the probability that $y_i\leq cx_i^{-1}$).

Here is the first paper that discusses this step (https://curate.nd.edu/downloads/df65v694z66)
Similar step can also be found in (https://www3.nd.edu/~mhaenggi/pubs/now.pdf,  pp. 206, and http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7412759, pp. 3961 and steps to get equation number 39)

[image]

In the above image $\Phi_y=\emptyset$ means that $h_xl(x-z)<y$ for all $x \in \Phi$.

[image]

For this case if we put $P_d=1,c=T$ then $x_i$ map to $d_i^{-\alpha_d}$ and $y_i$ map to $g_i$. And here we do not have any particular sign over the expectation.

Comment: It looks like you are taking the expectation of an inequality...so there must be a typo somewhere.  You can only take expectations of random variables.

Comment: @Michael yes you are right. I have corrected it. The $1$ represents the indicator function

Comment: How do you get the right-hand-side from the left-hand-side?  And what happened to the conditioning?

Comment: @Michael actually this is what I am interested in. I read this step in one of the research paper and I do not know how they handled the conditioning. Due to this reason I posted this question. I can refer the paper if it is needed

Comment: @Michael I do not know if it helps but here are some specifics of $x_i$ and $y_i$. $y_i's$ are exponentially distributed with mean $1$ and $x_i=d_i^{-\alpha}$ is the path loss for the $i-th$ interferer.

Comment: @Michael I have a reasoning in mind which make me think that the above step is wrong. Suppose all the $x_i's$ are one and further assume that we have only one term that is just $y_1$. Then in this case we will have $$E[y_1|y_1\leq c]$$ which is definitely  not equal to $$E_{Y_1}[y_11(y_1\leq c)]=\int_0^{c}y_1\exp(-y_1)dy_1$$. What do you say?

Comment: You seem to assume that $E(X_iY_i\mid A)=E(X_iY_i\mid A_i)$ with $A_j=[X_jY_j\leqslant c]$ for every $j$ and $A=\bigcap\limits_jA_j$. Why? Then your next step seems to be that $E(XY\mid XY\leqslant c)=E(Xg(X))$ where, for every $x$ (yes, correct notations should help distinguish between real numbers and random variables), $g(x)=E(Y\mathbf 1_{xY\leqslant c})$. This is obviously wrong, confusing integrating on an event and conditioning by this event but, indeed, if $(X,Y)$ is independent, then $E(XY\mathbf 1_{XY\leqslant c})=E(Xh(X))$ with $h(x)=E(Y\mathbf 1_{xY\leqslant c})$.

Comment: To sum up, please check the definition of the  conditional expectation.

Comment: @Did I agree with your definition of $A_j$ but I had a summation so I would say if there is only one term in the summation then your definition is right. Yes I should have written $E[Y_1|Y_1\leq c]$ and $E[Y_11(Y_1\leq c)]=\int_0^{c}y_1\exp(-y_1)dy_1$. I think in the research paper they have done the step (mentioned in my post) to simplify the derivation and make more tractable. Further I think the step will be accurate if $c \to \infty$.

Comment: "My" definition is exact with any number of terms, simply by linearity of conditional expectation. Anyway, why do you avoid the precise points made in my comment?

Comment: Although the points that you make in your comments are very clear and perhaps easy to understand, I avoid them because sometimes they are out of my thinking ability. Just as in this case I reduced the problem to a single term (it was just for my own understanding).

Comment: Stunning comment. (But please use @.)

Comment: @Did Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be a random variable, $\vec{Z}$ a random vector, and $\mathcal{A}$ an event with $P[\mathcal{A}]>0$. Some formulas that may help are:

1) Indicator function:
$$ \boxed{E[W|\mathcal{A}] = \frac{E[W1\{\mathcal{A}\}]}{P[\mathcal{A}]}} $$
So indeed we would need to divide by $P[\mathcal{A}]$ when using this indicator function formula.

2) Iterated expectation: 
$$ \boxed{E[W] = E[E[W|\vec{Z}]]}  $$
If PDFs exist and $Z$ is 1-dimensional then this is the same as
$$ E[W] = \int_{z=-\infty}^{\infty} E[W|Z=z]f_{Z}(z)dz $$

3) Conditioning on a world where $\mathcal{A}$ occurs:
$$ \boxed{E[W|\mathcal{A}] = E[E[W|\vec{Z}, \mathcal{A}]|\mathcal{A}]} $$
So conditioning on $\mathcal{A}$ must appear everywhere, and can only be removed or modified if more info is given.  If PDFs exist and $Z$ is 1-dimensional, this is the same as: 
$$ E[W|\mathcal{A}] = \int_{z=-\infty}^{\infty} E[W|Z=z,\mathcal{A}]f_{Z|\mathcal{A}}(z|\mathcal{A})dz$$

---

For your problem you can use either formula 1 or formula 3, but formula 3 is more direct. As suggested by Did, for each $i \in \{1, …, n\}$ define $\mathcal{A}_i = \{X_i Y_i \leq c \}$.  Define $\mathcal{A} = \cap_{i=1}^n \mathcal{A}_i$.

#### Via formula 3:

Fix $i \in \{1, …, n\}$.  Then:

\begin{align}
E[X_iY_i|\mathcal{A}] &= E[E[X_iY_i|X_i, \mathcal{A}]|\mathcal{A}]\\
&= E[X_i E[Y_i | X_i , \mathcal{A}]|\mathcal{A}] \\
&= E[X_i E[Y_i | X_i, \mathcal{A}_i]|\mathcal{A}] 
\end{align}
where the last equality uses 
$$E[Y_i|X_i, \mathcal{A}]=E[Y_i|X_i, \mathcal{A}_i]$$ 
which follows from the independence properties of $Y_i$.

#### Via formula 1:

Fix $i \in \{1, …, n\}$.  Then:

\begin{align}
E[X_iY_i | \mathcal{A}] &= \frac{E[X_i Y_i 1\{\mathcal{A}\}]}{P[\mathcal{A}]} \\
&= \frac{E[E[X_i Y_i 1\{\mathcal{A}\} | X_i, 1\{\mathcal{A}\}]]}{P[\mathcal{A}]}\\
&= \frac{E[X_i 1\{\mathcal{A}\} E[Y_i | X_i , 1\{\mathcal{A}\}]]}{P[\mathcal{A}]}\\
&=\frac{E[X_i 1\{\mathcal{A}\} E[Y_i | X_i , \mathcal{A}_i]]}{P[\mathcal{A}]}\\
&= E[X_i E[Y_i | X_i, \mathcal{A}_i]|\mathcal{A}] 
\end{align}
where the second-to-last equality uses 
$$ 1\{\mathcal{A}\} E[Y_i | X_i , 1\{\mathcal{A}\}] = 1\{\mathcal{A}\} E[Y_i | X_i , \mathcal{A}_i] $$
which again follows from the independence properties of $Y_i$.

#### Proof of formula 3:

Formula 3 is consistent with formula 1, indeed we get: 
\begin{align}
E[W|\mathcal{A}] &\overset{(a)}{=} \frac{E[W 1\{\mathcal{A}\}]}{P[\mathcal{A}]} \\
&= \frac{E[E[W 1\{\mathcal{A}\}|\vec{Z}, 1\{\mathcal{A}\} ]]}{P[\mathcal{A}]} \\
&= \frac{E[1\{\mathcal{A}\}E[W|\vec{Z}, 1\{\mathcal{A}\}]]}{P[\mathcal{A}]} \\
&\overset{(b)}{=} \frac{E[1\{\mathcal{A}\}E[W|\vec{Z}, \mathcal{A}]]}{P[\mathcal{A}]} \\
&\overset{(c)}=E[E[W|\vec{Z}, \mathcal{A}]|\mathcal{A}]
\end{align}
where (b) uses 
$$ 1\{\mathcal{A}\} E[W|\vec{Z}, 1\{\mathcal{A}\}] = 1\{\mathcal{A}\} E[W|\vec{Z}, \mathcal{A}] $$
and where (a) and (c) both use formula 1.

Comment: If you want to define $h_i(x) = E[Y_i|X_i=x, \mathcal{A}_i]$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $$E[X_iE[Y_i|X_i, \mathcal{A}_i]|\mathcal{A}_i] = E[X_ih_i(X_i)|\mathcal{A}_i]$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. As you mentioned that "the conditioning can be removed if more information is provided". I have attached the images (and their weblinks) where this step is done. I am not sure whether the steps are right in those papers or not.

Comment: I cannot follow that image, too much undefined notation.  I don't know how $I_{\phi}$ is defined, and I don't know what $\mathbb{E}^{!0}$ means.

Comment: $I_{\Phi}=\sum_{x \in \Phi}h_xl(x-z)$ where $\Phi$ is a two dimensional Poisson point process with uniform density $\lambda$ and $l(x-z)$ is the path loss between the locations $x$ and $z$. $E^{!0}$ is expectation over $h_x$'s and $l(x-z)$'s over the Poisson point process. $h_x$ is the small scale fading between the location $x$ and $z$. The third line is confusing since every thing is ok except the division by some probability. This the point I have problems in understanding.

Comment: What in the world does that superscript $!0$ mean over the expectation? I'm not exactly sure how that problem maps to your simplified problem, do the $h_x$'s map to the $X_i$s, and $l(x-z)$ map to $Y_i$?   Indeed it looks like they forgot to divide by a probability, unless that is incorporated in part of the constants.

Comment: $X_i$s map to $l(x-z)$ while $Y_i$s map to $h_x$. In this image $E^{!0}$ is expectation over some reduced palm measure. But If you look at the http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7412759&tag=1 equation 39 then it is actually expectation over the Poisson point process. I am going to add that image also.